# Color at ngx-admin (ng-star-inserted)

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, ngx-admin

I'm a new dev and I'm trying to change the color of those two areas. May any one assist me with that?

I learned that the class name for those are " ng-star-inserted " from the  "BrowserAnimationsModule" (the source code is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13e663c232dddc457e3f7243be404398624c9de6/packages/animations/browser/src/render/transition_animation_engine.ts#L25))

I used the corporate theme to create one on my on and changed all the color, but this one didn't change!

[First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn7tI.png)

[Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW4Sb.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please write the source code here, include the expected result an current result. Then people can help..

Comment: Thanks!
I just want to change the color of that... I have no code to write because I have no idea where to change..